# RSpec - How to create helper method available to tests that will automatically embed "it" tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to ruby/rails/rspec etc.

Using rspec 2.13.1, I want to create a module with a method that can be called from my tests resulting to subsequent calls of the "it" method of the RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.

My module:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module TestHelper
  def invalid_without(symbols)
    symbols = symbols.is_a?(Array) ? symbols : [symbols]
    symbols.each do |symbol|
      it "should not be valid without #{symbol.to_s.humanize}" do
        # Gonna nullify the subject's 'symbol' attribute here
        # and expect to have error on it
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The code above was added to:

```
spec/support/test_helper.rb
```

and in my spec_helper.rb, in the RSpec.configure block, I added the following:

```
config.include TestHelper
```

Now, in a test, I do the following:

```
describe Foo
    context "when invalid" do
        invalid_without [:name, :surname]
    end
end
```

Running this, I get:

```
undefined method `invalid_without' for #<Class:0x007fdaf1821030> (NoMethodError)
```

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [shared example group](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group).

```
shared_examples_for "a valid array" do |symbols|
  symbols = symbols.is_a?(Array) ? symbols : [symbols]
  symbols.each do |symbol|
    it "should not be valid without #{symbol.to_s.humanize}" do
      # Gonna nullify the subject's 'symbol' attribute here
      # and expect to have error on it
    end
  end
end

describe Foo do
  it_should_behave_like "a valid array", [:name, :surname]
end
```

Comment: I wanted to create a brand new method to accomplish this but your suggestion works great. Can't vote you up since I am a new member here... Thanks for your time.

Comment: Will find out how and I'll do it :)